# Using Char.chr in SML

Tags: char, sml

I need to convert an int to its equivalent char using the Char.chr-function, but why does the function return every char in the form of `#"\^A"` instead of just `#"A"` (that's how I want it to be).

Comment: It doesn't appear to for me. Can you give an example of code that you use where it does this?

Comment: @qaphla Hmm, strange. Just typing `Char.chr 1` for example returns `val it = #"\^A": char`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see there is just the way control characters (ASCII code 0-31) are pretty-printed by the interactive toplevel. For example, `#"\^A"` is equivalent to `#"\001"`. The SML system presumably uses its own `Char.toString` function to print values of type `char`. Try `chr 65`, which should be printed as `#"A"`.